# Add images from the path after specific word to MS Word

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I need to insert each images from the path after each specific word. I don't know what is wrong, and why this code doesn't work. this code runs with success but the images does not added to the document.

Here is my code.
`

```
public class ImageWord {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Open the MS Office document
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("C:\\test\\image.doc"));

        // Iterate through the paragraphs in the document
        List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = doc.getParagraphs();
        int imageCounter = 0;
        File[] images = new File("C:\\Users\\Screenshots\\").listFiles();
        for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : paragraphs) {
            // Iterate through the runs in the paragraph
            List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns();
            for (XWPFRun run : runs) {
                // Check if the run contains the word we want to insert the image after
                String text = run.getText(0);
                if (text != null && text.contains("word")) {
                    // Create a new run for the image
                    XWPFRun imageRun = paragraph.insertNewRun(runs.indexOf(run) + 1);

                    // Add the image to the run
                    String imgFile = images[imageCounter].getAbsolutePath();
                    imageRun.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFile), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile, 200, 200);
                    imageCounter++;
                    if (imageCounter >= images.length) {
                        imageCounter = 0;
                    }
                    // Add a line break after the image
                    imageRun.addBreak();
                }
            }
        }
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\test\\images.doc");
        doc.write(out);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't include more details, nobody can help you. Does your code throw any Exception when you run it?

Comment: Code runs with success but the images does not added to the document.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
imageRun.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFile), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile, 200, 200);
```

adds a picture to the `XWPFRun` which is 200 EMU width and 200 EMU high.

What is EMU? See: http://polymathprogrammer.com/2009/10/22/english-metric-units-and-open-xml/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML_file_formats#DrawingML

> A DrawingML graphic's dimensions are specified in English Metric Units
> (EMUs). It is so called because it allows an exact common
> representation of dimensions originally in either English or Metric
> units—defined as 1/360,000 of a centimeter, and thus there are 914,400
> EMUs per inch, and 12,700 EMUs per point, to prevent round-off in
> calculations.

So your added picture is **very** small. It is not even a pixel (or a point) width and high. So it is not visible.

As documented in [XWPFRun.addPicture](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#addPicture-java.io.InputStream-int-java.lang.String-int-int-%3C):

> public XWPFPicture addPicture...
>
> Adds a picture to the run. This method handles attaching the picture
> data to the overall file.
>
> Parameters: ...
>
> width - width in EMUs. To
> convert to / from points use
> [Units](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/util/Units.html)
>
> height - height in EMUs. To convert to / from points use
> [Units](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/util/Units.html)

So try using:

```
imageRun.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFile), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile, Units.pixelToEMU(200), Units.pixelToEMU(200));
```

if the 200 means pixel.

Or

```
imageRun.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFile), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile, Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(200));
```

if the 200 means points.

---

The above is one problem. But seeing your code I doubt it is the only one.

The code line `for (XWPFRun run : runs) {` should throw `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` when the code in `if (text != null && text.contains("word")) {...}` gets reached. `XWPFRun run : runs` internally uses an `Iterator` which gets damaged if `paragraph.insertNewRun` inserts a new XWPFRun in `paragraph`.  So if there is no error, then `text.contains("word")` never gets true. Try debugging:

```
...
                String text = run.getText(0);
                System.out.println(text);
                if (text != null && text.contains("word")) {
                    System.out.println(text + " contains word");
...
```

Is there a run which contains "word"?

To avoid the `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` do using:

```
...
            //for (XWPFRun run : runs) {
            for (int r = 0; r < runs.size(); r++) {
                XWPFRun run = runs.get(r);
                // Check if the run contains the word we want to insert the image after
                String text = run.getText(0);
                System.out.println(text);
                if (text != null && text.contains("word")) {
                    System.out.println(text + " contains word");
                    // Create a new run for the image
                    XWPFRun imageRun = paragraph.insertNewRun(runs.indexOf(run) + 1);
 
                    // Add the image to the run
                    String imgFile = images[imageCounter].getAbsolutePath();
                    //imageRun.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFile), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile, 200, 200);
                    imageRun.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFile), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile, Units.pixelToEMU(200), Units.pixelToEMU(200));
                    imageCounter++;
                    if (imageCounter >= images.length) {
                        imageCounter = 0;
                    }
                    // Add a line break after the image
                    imageRun.addBreak();
                }
            }
...
```

---

If `(text != null && text.contains("word"))` never gets true, then it might be that no stored text run in the Word document fully contains the text "word". Word is very special in splitting text in text runs. Not only formatting leads to split text runs. Also spell checker splits text in different text runs to mark errors. And sometimes Word is just crazy in how it splits text in text runs. So it can be that the text "word" is stored so: `<r>w</r<r>ord</r>`.

To overcome those issues, [TextSegment](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/TextSegment.html) was introduced in Apache POI. It can be got via [XWPFParagraph.searchText](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#searchText-java.lang.String-org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.PositionInParagraph-).

Using this, following code should be a better working version of your code sample:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import java.util.List;

public class ImageWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 
         // Open the MS Office document
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./image.docx"));

        List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = doc.getParagraphs();
        int imageCounter = 0;
        File[] images = new File("./images/").listFiles();
        String textToFind = "word";
        
        // Iterate through the paragraphs in the document
        for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : paragraphs) {
            TextSegment foundTextSegment = null;
            PositionInParagraph startPos = new PositionInParagraph(0, 0, 0);
            // Search all text segments having text to find
            while((foundTextSegment = paragraph.searchText(textToFind, startPos)) != null) {
                List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns();
                XWPFRun endRun = runs.get(foundTextSegment.getEndRun());

                System.out.println("Run " + endRun + " contains " + textToFind);
                
                // Create a new run for the image
                XWPFRun imageRun = paragraph.insertNewRun(runs.indexOf(endRun) + 1);
                runs = paragraph.getRuns();
                // Add the image to the run
                String imgFile = images[imageCounter].getAbsolutePath();
                imageRun.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFile), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile, Units.pixelToEMU(200), Units.pixelToEMU(200));
                imageCounter++;
                if (imageCounter >= images.length) {
                    imageCounter = 0;
                }
                // Add a line break after the image
                imageRun.addBreak();
                // Get the next start position for search after new inserted image run
                startPos = new PositionInParagraph(runs.indexOf(imageRun), 0, 0);
            }
        }
        
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./images.docx");
        doc.write(out);
        out.close();
    }
}
```